# blender models are not exporting the materials when exporting to unity. help pls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, modeling

when i export my model from blender to unity, it doesn't take the textures with it.

Comment: Did you try to reassign the according textures in the albedo (And if needed normal map, etc) of the materials in Unity?

Comment: Not on a PC right now but your blender model seems to use some textures (image files) you might need to reassign in the materials in Unity

Comment: ok @derHugo , thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using cycles, you need to [bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html) your materials into a UV map. And then using baked images, you will set up material in Unity and assign it to the model.